# How can I add data from a form into my sql table using node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm making a website on the local host 8080, using node.js and mysql I've tried to make a module of my sign up page using form get method and parse the link into the sql command. Here is the code I have for myModule.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');
var con;

exports.connectToDB = function () {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "adminps", // SQL PASSWORD
        database: "project_dev2"
    });
    return con;
};


exports.addUser = function (res, user_em_id, user_f_name, user_l_name, user_email, user_password, myCallback) {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (user_em_id, user_f_name, user_l_name, user_email, user_password) values ( '" +
    user_em_id + "','" + user_f_name + "','" + user_l_name + "','" + user_email +"','" + user_password + "')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        myCallback(res, result); // result - employee titles object
    });
};
```

Here is my server.js (the one I'm running on node.js to start the project):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var myModule = require('./myModule')
var mySess = require('./mySession')
querystring = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    var s;

    if (req.url=="/login") {

        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });

        req.on('end', () => {

            body = querystring.parse(body);

            myModule.authenticateUser(res,body,mySess, myModule.postAuthentication);  
        });

    } else if (req.url == "/registration") {  
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
    
        req.on('end', () => {
            // Parse the data if needed
            body = querystring.parse(body);

            myModule.navReg(res, body);
        });
    } else if (req.url.indexOf("/register") >= 0) {
        var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    
        myModule.addUser(res, q.user_em_id, q.user_f_name, q.user_l_name, q.user_email, q.user_password, myModule.navReg);
    } else {
        // Login page.
        myModule.login(res);
    }

}).listen(8080)
```